# Haskell in the security industry?

Tags: penetration-test, tools

I know of a tool called [msf-haskell](https://github.com/GaloisInc/msf-haskell) for security but are there others?

1. Are there any security tools that are written in haskell?  **other
   than the one above**
2. How much use will haskell be in industry, rather than using python or ruby?
3. Can you write exploits in haskell?

Comment: your question 1. is for product recommendation (and does a google search not awnser it?) 
   
2. is primarily opinion  based, even a big assumption about the use of python and ruby. 
3. Yes, exploits can be written in any language. this question shows lack of understanding about programming languages as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Google/Github should be able to help you with this question.
2. The language a tool was written in only matter if you're looking at the source to extend/enhance/troubleshoot the tool and in that case the usefulness of haskell is increased for people that know haskell and decreased for people who don't know haskell
3. You can write exploits in any language, you don't even need programming at all to write exploits, in many cases a text/hex editor is all that is required.